# How to fix the problem of include Path in Visual Studio Code Linux?

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using VSCode in Linux for my project. I have this curly line under the include lines of my header files [image]

I included correctly the include path as defined in the file c_cpp_proprieties.json as follow:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",

    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Please any solution to resolve this problem.

Comment: Microsoft C/C++ extension: Enable logging.    Go to settings. Search for logging. Click C/C++ to narrow results. Change logging to Debug.   On the Terminal OUTPUT window change dropdown menu to C/C++.   Check logs for the "include: path" lines. They'll appear whenever you switch to different C++ files. It will tell you what paths are being processed.   Note: "include:" lines are for the Default Intellisense engine and "Folder:"/"Processing Folder:" are for Tag Parser Intellisense engine. The extension still uses the Tag Parser engine for some things even though Default Intellisense is enabled.

Comment: @boocs No need for logs in this case, just hovering the mouse over the red "squigglies" will (should) tell what the issue is. \@op Try removing the '/' from the path. Sometimes this will result in '//' when expanded. Bash is ok with this, but I am not sure about Code. I need to conf mine for current workspace, so I will test it. Let us know what you get on hover.

Comment: the modification of longing doesn't help!

Answer (score 0):

When you compile it on gcc you have to include the include library.
The include path in settings didn't work out for me.
Changing it on the build task for gcc did fix it.

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "-I",
            "${workspaceFolder}/ds/include/",
            "${workspaceFolder}/ds/src/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.c",      
            "-o",
            "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/gcc"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the desired path in the `c_cpp_properties.json` as well as the folder to the Visual Studio Code workspace (File -> Add folder to workspace) appeared to solve the issue for me.